# Multiple UITextFields and textDidChangeNotification notification

Tags: swift, uikit, combine

I was playing with Combine framework lately and was wondering if it is possible to create some smart extension to get text changes as Publisher.

Let's say I've got two UITextFields:

```
firstTextField.textPub.sink {
    self.viewModel.first = $0
}

secondTextField.textPub.sink {
    self.viewModel.second = $0
}
```

where first and second variable is just `@Published var first/second: String = ""

```
extension UITextField {
    var textPub: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        return NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification)
            .map {
                guard let textField = $0.object as? UITextField else { return "" }
                return textField.text ?? ""
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because I'm using shared instance of NotificationCenter so when I make any change to any of textFields it will propagate new value to both `sink` closures. Do you think is there any way to achieve something similar to `rx.text` available in RxSwift? I was thinking about using `addTarget` with closure but it would require using associated objects from Objective-C.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured this out. We can pass object using NotificationCenter and then filter all instances that are not matching our instance. It seems to work as I expected:

```
extension UITextField {
    var textPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Never> {
        NotificationCenter.default
            .publisher(for: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: self)
            .compactMap { $0.object as? UITextField }
            .map { $0.text ?? "" }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add subscribers to the view modal, and connect them a text field publisher within the context of the view controller.

NotificationCenter is useful to dispatch events app-wide; there's no need to use it when connecting items that are fully owned by the View Controller. However, once you've updated the view modal it may make sense to publish a 'View Modal Did Change' event to NotificationCenter.

Comment: yes, but it requires adding target to each textFields and assigning text to `@Published` property.